# Detect a player that is nearest to a selected entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to kill an entity that is nearest to the player. 
So I put the command:

`/kill @p[type=armor_stand,c=1]`

So I was thinking, is it possible to reverse it to "kill a player that is nearest to an entity"?

Comment: you can't combine `@p` with `type=armor_stand`. @p selects the closest player, not the closest entity. use @e instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to kill the entity that is the closest one to the player you can do

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /kill @e[type=!player,c=1]
```

in reverse, to kill the player that is the closest to an entity, you can do

```
/execute @e[yourEntityHere] ~ ~ ~ /kill @p
```

---

be aware that `@p` only selects the closest, non-dead player that matches the given criteria and can't be used to select entities.